# JDBC - Resultset data processing : Strange behaviour : default fetchsize returned

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a oracle(10.2) PLSQL procedure which fetches 15 records from a table in a sysrefcursor.
I then pass this cursor to a java class as a resultset. This java class is loaded to oracle.

Driver name : Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version : 10.2.0.1.0
Driver Major Version : 10
Driver Minor Version : 2

**Observations:**

1 Inside the java class, when I iterate through the resultset I get only the first 10 records.

2 If the cursor fetched (20 or more records) or (10 or less) I could get all the records while iterating the resultset.

3 I found that the default fetchsize for the resultset is 10. If I change the fetchSize to 5, and the cursor fetches 8 records, I could get the first 5 records while iterating the resultset.

4 If the cursor fetched (10 or more records) or (5 or less) I could get all the records while iterating the resultset.

5 If I change the resultset fetchSize to 1, I could get all the records in the resultset no matter how many records are fetched by the cursor.

Why is the resultset behaving weirdly?

```
public static BLOB createZip(BLOB prevBlob, String outPrefix, ResultSet entries, ResultSet rs, Long[] resultRows) throws Exception
{
    OracleConnection conn = null;
    BLOB retBLOB = null;
    int page   = 1;
    int curRow = 0;
    long totalRows = 0;
    try
    {
        conn = (OracleConnection) new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
        ArrayList entryList = loadEntries(entries);
        retBLOB = BLOB.createTemporary(conn, true, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
        retBLOB.open(BLOB.MODE_READWRITE);
        OutputStream bOut = retBLOB.setBinaryStream(0L);
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(bOut);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(zipOut);
        zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(outPrefix + "-p" + page + ".csv"));
        writeHeader(out, entryList);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            curRow++;
            totalRows++;
            if (curRow >= maxPageSize)
            {
                zipOut.closeEntry();
                page++;
                zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(outPrefix + "-p" + page + ".csv"));
                writeHeader(out, entryList);
                curRow = 0;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < entryList.size(); i++)
            {
                Entry e = (Entry) entryList.get(i);
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    out.print(",");
                }
                if (e.isEscape())
                    out.print("\"" + escapeExcel(rs.getString(e.getColumn())) + "\"");
                else
                    out.print("\"" + emptyExcel(rs.getString(e.getColumn())) + "\"");
            }
            out.println();
        }

        if (totalRows == 0)
        {
            out.println("\"No Entries Found\"");
        }
        resultRows[0] = new Long(totalRows);
        out.flush();
        zipOut.closeEntry();
        if (prevBlob != null)
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            InputStream bIn = prevBlob.binaryStreamValue();
            ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(bIn);

            ZipEntry inEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
            while (inEntry != null)
            {
                zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(inEntry.getName()));
                int len;
                while ((len = zipIn.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                inEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
            }

            zipIn.close();

            try
            {
                prevBlob.freeTemporary();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) { }

        }

        zipOut.close();
        retBLOB.close();
        return retBLOB;
    }
    catch (Exception sex)
    {
        if (retBLOB != null)
        {
            try
            {
                retBLOB.freeTemporary();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) { }
        }
        throw sex;
    }
    finally
    {

        try { entries.close(); } catch (SQLException sex) { }
        try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException sex) { }
        try
        {
            if (conn != null || !conn.isClosed())
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: *Why is the resultset behaving weirdly?* statistically it is a lot more likely that you have a bug in your code and that the ResultSet is behaving as intended. Can you share a sample of your code ?

Comment: I have shared the code. It doesn't look like I m doing something wrong.

Comment: Looks complex, but okay... Does this also happen when you remove all other code (opening another connection, creating a blob, reading from the second result set) except the loop over rs (and maybe rs.getString in the loop)?

Comment: You were right. Thanks. It behaved normally without the 'other codes'. Let me debug more into it.

Comment: If I have <code>rs.getString(e.getColumn())<code> in my code, then the issue crops up. Otherwise its fine.

Comment: If I fetch the value using the column index, it works fine <code>rs.getString(index)</code>. But if I try to fetch even the column name then the issue surfaces.<code>rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(j)</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround. I fetched the column index before `while(rs.next())`.
The below snippet works absolutely fine for me. But I still fail to understand why `resultSet.getString(columnName);` failed inside `while(rs.next())`.

```
    ArrayList entryList = loadEntries(entries);
    int[] colIndx = new int[entryList.size()];
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < entryList.size(); i++){
       Entry e = (Entry) entryList.get(i);
       for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns; j++){
          if(rsmd.getColumnName(j).equalsIgnoreCase(e.getColumn()))
              colIndx[i] = j;
       }
    }
    try{
        while (rs.next()){
            for (int i = 0; i < colIndx.length ; i++){
                System.out.println("Column Values["+colIndx[i]+"] : "+rs.getString(colIndx[i]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems strange indeed. You may have found a bug. By any chance does the cursor have two columns with the same name ?

Comment: If it were easy to do that, I'd say file a bug with Oracle.